Which position is more sensitive to feeling an earthquake?
There was an earthquake today in the NYC metro area.
I know a few people that didn’t feel the earthquake while standing. Whereas everyone that was sitting felt it.
Are those standing less apt to feel an earthquake compared to those sitting?
Thanks.

Only thing I can come up with is the sense of balance from the inner ear. While standing or moving, our mind might be attuned to attribute changes to our own movement. Just speculating.
